# No enumerate in [turkish]{babel} package

Tags: enumerate, babel

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*)]
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

in log file;

[image]

If it is `%\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` no problem, MWE is working. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turkish makes `=` active which is a known source of problems with keyval-arguments. You can deactivate it with `\shorthandoff`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*)]
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Perfect working.